# Can I recover from the consequences of Salt's Curse?

Tags: sunless-sea

During my last trip out to the zee, I received Salt's curse. The consequences of which was that

> after I returned to London I received the news that my scion has disappeared, essentially removing my ability to pick two legacies for my next playthrough.

Is there any way to recover what I had lost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't yet had a child, or had a child but haven't yet raised their Zee Fever to 25, you can repeat that process on your current captain to gain a new Scion.

If you have already sent your current captain's child to zee, you cannot regain Scion until your next captain.

If you gain Salt's Curse again but have not defied the gods, you can remove the curse at the House of the Question in Whither at a cost of one Zee-ztory and seven Secrets.

Comment: If you are playing as natural philosopher, you can regain Scion if you save your father successfully.